# How to fix "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/http/HttpRequestInitializer" runtime error?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I only beginning to learn, how to use java with Goole App Engine Standard.
I use Eclipse 4.6.3 for that.
I created web project and coded some junk, then I decided to try list files at Google Cloud Storage.
Here is my code:

```
public static ArrayList<String> getFilesInBucket(String bucket_name)
{
/*Line 235*/GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(RetryParams.getDefaultInstance());

    ListResult result = null;
    try { result = gcsService.list(bucket_name, ListOptions.DEFAULT); }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (result.hasNext())
    {
        ListItem l = result.next();

        if (!l.isDirectory())
            files.add(l.getName());
    }

    return files;
}
```

This junk works locally, but after I deploy this it stops. I see errors in Google Console:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/http/HttpRequestInitializer
at MyJunk.getFilesInBucket (ADServlet.java:235)
```

Every jar that is added to lib directory in src is also added into web-inf/lib.
[image]

I also added this jars here:
[image]

I even opened problems tab and quick fixed every "Eclipse warning: XXXXXXXXXXX.jar will not be exported or published." junk by this:
[image]

(This is not my screen).

And yet my code fails at runtime on GAE Standard... What else I can do to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Cloud libraries have a lot of dependencies.  Rather than try to chase them down by hand, let your machine do it for you.  Two suggestions:

1. Use the [Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse).  Use *Properties > Configure > Convert to App Engine Standard Project*, and then *Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries* and select *Add Library… > Google API Libraries* and select *Google Cloud Storage*.
2. Convert your project to Maven or Gradle and then [add the documented dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java).

Comment: Thank you. Me helped `Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries and select Add Library… > Google API Libraries and select Google Cloud Storage` this step.